# Having trouble AFTER form submission with zombie.js

Tags: forms, authentication, coldfusion, zombie.js

I have the following setup on my site:

You enter credentials on a login page and that takes you to a second page (which normally produces no screen output) which validates the user and redirects them to the appropriate homepage.

My step definitions consist of three steps:

1. Load up initial login page.
2. Enter credentials and submit.
3. Verify (by checking page title) that I made it in the homepage.

My first step passes with flying colors.

My second step claims to pass.

My third step fails.

Upon review, I found that it's because the second step, while officially it didn't fail, didn't do what it was supposed to do.  Zombie got stuck on the validation page.  At first I thought it was just missing the redirect, but it seems that it doesn't execute ANYTHING on the validation page.  I even commented out the entire page and simply put an output of "Hello" at the top of the page.  If my browser.html(); can be believed, it doesn't even see that.  I know I make it to the second page because I have

```
console.log("\n" + browser.location.href);
```

which shows me the URL of the second page.

I then have

```
console.log(browser.html());
```

which is empty.

I even have a:

```
browser.wait(10000,callback);
```

beforehand to give it some processing time but to no avail.

Some information that might be relevant:

This is a ColdFusion site.  I know zombie's handling the concept of CF since it's loading the login page initially, although there's not much actual CF processing going on there.

There's DB access happening.  If zombie is accessing like a regular browser, it shouldn't make a difference, but it's there.  Although even when I comment everything out, it still doesn't work, so I doubt that's actually relevant.

This is my script portion for the login step.  Please advise if I'm approaching this the wrong way.

---

```
  this.When(/^I input my credentials$/, function(callback) {

    browser.fill("login", "myusername").fill("password", "mypassword");

    browser.document.forms[0].submit();

    // Put in here to account for redirect time it will take to get past validation page to actual home page

    browser.wait(10000,callback);

    callback();
    });
```

---

If you need any other information, please let me know. I would appreciate any help whatsoever in being able to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your problem, but it looks like this may be an issue with the way you are handling asynchronous calls. At any rate, you should not need to `browser.wait` for something like this at all. Try something like the following:

```
this.When(/^I input my credentials$/, function(callback) {
    browser
        .fill("login", "myusername")
        .fill("password", "mypassword")
        .pressButton("#selectorForYourButton", function (err) {
            // Check for errors or any other behaviour this test is actually about
            callback();
        });
});
```

First, the `pressButton` method is preferable because it gets closer to testing actual browser interaction. But more importantly, `callback()` is only executed after all the events fired off by pressing the button have been resolved.